# Binding static and dynamic classes with HTMLBars

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, htmlbars

I'm trying to bind a static class 'form-control' and a dynamic property value 'color' to the class attribute of an input helper, however, the syntax I'm using just outputs this to the rendered DOM element

```
class="form-control {{color}}"
```

without actually binding the value of 'color' to the class attribute. I know that this is the way to bind static and dynamic classes in normal DOM elements with HTMLBars, but is there a different syntax for elements that use curly-braces?

The syntax I'm using:

```
{{input class="form-control {{color}}" value=property.value type="text"}}
```

Answer (score 6):

The double curly braces syntax invoke a helper or path in handlebars. But from within a helper you cannot use them to invoke a sub expression. Instead you have to use parenthesis to invoke a sub expression. For instance:

Wrong

```
{{input value={{uppercase user.name}} }}
```

Correct

```
{{input value=(uppercase user.name) }}
```

Because handlebars does not permit to interpolate literal values with dynamic ones. You'll need to use some custom helper to achieve what you want. Ember 1.3.2 comes with a `concat` helper, so you can use it like this:

```
{{input class=(concat "form-control " color) value=property.value type="text"}}
```

Notice the space in the end of "form-control" class, this is needed because the concat helper doesn't add any separator in the moment.

If you're using an old version, you can create a `join-params` helper to handle this for you:

**app/helpers/join-params.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export function joinParams(params) {
  return params.join(' ');
}

export default Ember.HTMLBars.makeBoundHelper(joinParams);
```

And then use it without appending the space in the end of "form-control" class

```
{{input class=(join-params "form-control" color) value=property.value type="text"}}
```