# How can I add a class to a div from a component in emberjs?

Tags: ember.js

I have the `main-navbar` component.

The **app/templates/components/main-navbar.hbs** file looks like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Blog</li>
</ul>
<button> Add class </button>
```

When I click on the button I want the `ul` element to recieve a **test** class `<ul class='test'>` and when I click again the button, the **test** class to be removed.

How can I achieve this action for the button? I assume that the **app/components/main-navbar.js** file must be used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binding static and dynamic classes with HTMLBars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31101967/binding-static-and-dynamic-classes-with-htmlbars)

Comment: Hi Christian, I've noticed you've posted a couple Ember.js questions. I suggest that you give our official Guides a good read, and join our Slack channel, we have a great _#-help_ channel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should look at [this part](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/components/customizing-a-components-element/#toc_customizing-the-element-s-class) of the guides, it describes how to do this exactly.You'll just bind to a property with classNameBindings if your component has tagName: 'ul'.

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  classNameBindings: ['test'],
  test: false,
  actions:{
    toggled(){
      this.toggleProperty('test')
    }
  }
});
```

Ah hold on, you're setting the class on another element, adding that now.

```
class="{{if somethingEnabled 'test' 'empty'}}"
```

Here is a [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/7e03985ec7b2fa5bb84b87d3b1f33667?openFiles=styles.app.css%2Ctemplates.components.nav-bar.hbs) with this implemented.